# Toggle button with an image in xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

i am using Button as beow to show the add to cart button with image in the xaml view

```
<Button x:Name="cartbutton" Grid.Row="0" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference ListItemPage}, Path=BindingContext.CartCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start" Image="lowim.png" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="0,5,5,0" />
```

and use in the MVVM inside the constructor as below

```
CartCommand = new Command<Resturent>(OnCartCommand);
```

then i am using MVVM with dependency injection where i only get the Icommand of the button click in the view model as below

```
public ICommand CartCommand { get; set; }

public async void OnCartCommand(Resturent restoraunt)
{
  await DialogService.DisplayAlert("CART DETAILS", "ITEM"+ restoraunt.Name+ "SUCESSFULLY ADDED", "OK");
}
```

i am expecting to create a toggle button where when i click on the button ( where the user add the items to the cart by pressing button with image lowim.png as shown above) then the image of the button suppose to change ( with another image icon lets say add.jpg). support in this regard will be highly appreciated and thank you advance for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, all you have to do is create a converter something like this:

```
 public class ConverterAddRemoveImage : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool isAddedToCart = (bool)value;
        if (isAddedToCart)
        {
            return "PositiveImage"; //This will be a string
        }
        else
        {
            return "NegativeImage";  //This will be a string
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then you need to define it in the XAML resource dictionary of your XAML page something like this:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
        <common:ConverterAddRemoveImage x:Key="AddRemoveImage" />
</ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Where common is the namespace where your converter is present.

The image source would be something like this:

```
Source="{Binding IsAddedToCart, Converter={StaticResource AddRemoveImage}}
```

Where is added to cart is a bool property in your model something like this :

```
  private bool isInCart;
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  public bool IsAddedToCart
    {
        get
        {
            return isInCart;
        }
        set
        {
            isInCart= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsAddedToCart));
        }
    }
 private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

**Note:** Your model class must inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface

Now, as soon as you change your model bool property it will change the image accordingly.

Goodluck revert in case of any queries

Comment: thank you so much for the support and really appreciate it, there is a little confusion for me how do i declare the image in xaml ?? is it like this  <Button x:Name="cartbutton" Grid.Row="0" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference ListItemPage}, Path=BindingContext.CartCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start"  Image="{Binding IsAddedToCart, Converter={StaticResource AddRemoveImage}}" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Margin="0,5,5,0" /> or how do i declare the source along with image , please help, thanks

Comment: Yeah you will do it like you have done it in your comment, i did not see you were using a button i thought it was an image control my bad sorry

Comment: @ Hakim, when build there are no errors , but when the application deploy and run it throws exception like below "Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." , as far as i feel their is something wrong about way we bind to the image as source for the button but when i give as text its running but not changing the text even i tapped if you can send the email i can send you screenshots , any idea what will be the issue ??? ( i m so grateful to you for your support i don't mind donating you for your valuable time )

Comment: Email me at hakimgulamali88@gmail.com waiting!!

Comment: I just sent you a mail, Thanks and please let me know if you haven't got my mail.

Comment: Thank you, I will be waiting for your favorable response :-)

Comment: I have responded kindly take a look and do reply!