# Xamarin Image Source Click for Navigation Image

Tags: image, xamarin, click

I have used images for my sub navigation in my app and I'd simply like to change the image to a black and white image when it is clicked. The code for this is help in my App static resources so it is the same for all pages. Please can you advise on I can do this is image gestures already used?

'''code'''

```
<Image Source = "homebtn2.png" x:Name="btnHome"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                        HeightRequest="36" WidthRequest="46"    Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Center" >
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer  Tapped="homepageButtonClicked"  />
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>

 void homepageButtonClicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        App.MenuIsPresented = false;
        btnHome.Source = "homebtn2BlackWhite.png";
        App.NavigationPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage(new   myHomePageViewModel()));
        
    }
```

'''code'''

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Toggle button with an image in xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52057695/toggle-button-with-an-image-in-xamarin)

Comment: `Please can you advise on I can do this is image gestures already used?` Do you want to change the image's icon back into the previous image's icon after tapping on it?